# Heroku - make changes on the fly

Tags: git, heroku

I was able to upload my play2 application to heroku.

I did the following.

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "init"

$ heroku create --stack cedar
$ git push heroku master
```

I want to make changes to my running application. I read though https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git but I still have problems.

How do I tell heroku/git that I made a change and I want to update my running application?

I've tried `$ git push heroku master` again, but it tells me everything is up to date, which is wrong. So I guess there should be a command to update the git repository?

I've never worked with git and it seems that the documentation on heroku is lacking of some information.

I hope you can clear things up for me.

Comment: You'll need to learn Git well before this will be smooth running for you. [Here's a reference](http://learn.github.com/p/intro.html). [Here's an interactive one](http://try.github.com/levels/1/challenges/1).

Comment: nice it works!thank you very much , git is really cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to commit your changes to your local Git repo before you push them:

```
git add app/FileYouChanged
git commit -m "message about your changes"
```

Then you can push your Git repo to Heroku:

```
git push heroku master
```